# Functions inside controllerTextDidBeginEditing triggers controllerTextDidEndEditing

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

Have an interesting situation I'm hoping someone has addressed before:

I have an NSTextField. When the user enters text into this text field it sends the controlTextDidBeginEditing notification which triggers my override function in my delegate.  This is working correctly so far, but there's a side effect I didn't anticipate.

The functions I call within my override controlTextDidBeginEditing block causes the NSTextField to lose focus, which triggers the controlTextDidEndEditing notification before the user is finished entering all of their information.

Let's say the user is entering "Hello." into the text field.

Basically, what I want is this:

1. User types "H" key.
2. textDidBeginEditing does some functions
3. User then types "ello." keys but nothing is triggered.
4. User is finished and hits
5. textDidEndEditing does some different functions

What is actually happening is this:

1. User types "H" key.
2. textDidBeginEditing does some functions
3. these functions trigger textDidEndEditing
4. textDidEndEditing does it's functions
5. repeat steps 1-4 for each of the additional keys the user hits.

The problem is that the functions are time dependent.  In other words, it's important that they happen when the user hits the first key of the text he is entering.

It seems to me that using both textDidBeginEditing and textDidEndEditing in the way I'm trying to use them isn't going to work for my purposes and I'm wondering if there is a way around this.

As I'm typing this, I'm thinking that perhaps checking the last key the user hit and only calling the functions inside the textDidEndEditing block if that key is the Return/Enter key or the Tab key may solve my problem, but maybe there's a better way.

I would love to hear everyone's ideas on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Which functionality do you need and which functions do you call?

Comment: The are all custom functions in my ViewController class.  The functions do things like clear all of the text fields (which pulls focus from the main text field I'm monitoring.)

I did find a workaround, but it's a bit clunky.  Basically, I set up some boolean variables to make sure that the code in didBeginEditing only executes the 1st time it receives, and another to make sure the didEndEditing only executes it's code the last time it receives the notification, resetting the bools in the process so it's ready for next time.

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Clearing other text fields doesn't pull the focus from the current focused field. How do you clear the text fields?

Comment: by assigning textField.stringValue = ""

Comment: Setting `stringValue` doesn't change the focus and doesn't trigger `textDidEndEditing`. Do you set `stringValue` of the focused field?

Comment: Not intentionally... I'll have to go through all the methods to see, but I don't think so.